# How do I get a space or line break between paragraphs rather than an indent? Parskip is not working

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, indentation, paragraphs, parskip

So when I first started out with my file I had gaps between paragraphs and no indent, as I was using the parskip package as listed below in my pre amble. At some point for a reason unbeknown to me this stopped working and now I have indents separating paragraphs and no line break at all. Have tried loads of different things but can't seem to find the problem. Perhaps it's a contradiction in one of the packages I included later on?? Thank you in advance for any advice you may be able to give!

Here's my pre amble:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}      
\usepackage{geometry}                       
\geometry{a4paper}                 
%\geometry{landscape}         
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}   
\pagenumbering{arabic}                          
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[square,authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\graphicspath{ {paperfigures/} }
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[font={footnotesize}]{caption}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fullpage}
```

Comment: id you try removing them one at a time or putting `parskip` last?

Answer (score 0):

Your preamble is not very helpful ... you need to shorten it to only relevant packages, for which you find that changed document layout. As far I see, no one from preamble influence on it.

Tray the following MWE, if it works for you:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

If result is as you like to have, add to above MWE packages which you really need in your document.

Package `lipsum` is for dummy text, with `\setlength...` the indent is set to zero (as you like to have) and vertical space between paragraphs.

Hope this will help you to find desired solution/document yayout.